# pkg-config --libs returns a .la file, but g++ can't handle it

Tags: linux, g++, ld, libtool

I'm trying to build something against GStreamer from git. They have some magic process that makes `pkg-config` happy, but if I run it, I get a `.la` file:

```
$ pkg-config --libs gstreamer-1.0
/home/blong/gst/head/gstreamer/gst/libgstreamer-1.0.la -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
```

And that causes problems for GCC:

```
g++ -o example switchtrackexample.cpp `pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0`
# comes out as: g++ -o example switchtrackexample.cpp -pthread -I/home/blong/gst/head/gstreamer -I/home/blong/gst/head/gstreamer/libs -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include /home/blong/gst/head/gstreamer/gst/libgstreamer-1.0.la -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
/usr/bin/ld: error: /home/blong/gst/head/gstreamer/gst/libgstreamer-1.0.la:8:8: invalid character
/usr/bin/ld: error: /home/blong/gst/head/gstreamer/gst/libgstreamer-1.0.la:8:8: syntax error, unexpected $end
/usr/bin/ld: error: /home/blong/gst/head/gstreamer/gst/libgstreamer-1.0.la: not an object or archive
# lots of undefined references here
```

I've read some things suggesting I should be able to use `libtool` to compile this, but I can't figure out how. What am I supposed to do with this `.la` file?

Answer (score 0):

It figures, right after I asked this, I [found this answer](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/libgstreamer-0-10-la-file-not-recognized-td2341222.html) by Julien Moutte:

> Add :
>   libtool --mode=link
>   in front of your build command.

Following that advice, I get this, which works:

```
libtool --mode=link g++ -o example switchtrackexample.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0`
```